# How to handle escape characters in pyspark. Trying to replace escape character with NULL, when column value is '\026' in dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, stringescapeutils

How to handle escape characters in pyspark. Trying to replace escape character with NULL

'\026' is randomly spreadout through all the columns and I have replace to '\026'  with NULL across all columns

below is my sample input data

```
col1,col2,col3,Col4    
1,\026\026,abcd026efg,1|\026\026|abcd026efg            
2,\026\026,\026\026\026,2|026\026|\026\026\026         
3,ad026eg,\026\026,3|ad026eg|\026\026       
4,ad026eg,xyad026,4|ad026eg|xyad026
```

and, my out data should be

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|      
1,NULL,abcd026efg,1||abcd026efg|   
2,NULL,NULL,2|NULL|NULL|   
3,ad026eg,NULL,3|ad026eg|NULL|       
4,ad026eg,xyad026,4|ad026eg|xyad026|
```

Note: Col4 is combined columns of col1, col2, col3 with | delimited

```
 df.withColumn('col2',F.regexp_replace('col2','\D\d+',None)).show().
 This is working but it is replacing all the cell values with NULL.
```

Comment: what happens if you use ```''``` instead of ```None```?

Comment: Can you correct the formatting of your input and output data? It is bit difficult to distinguish between your column value and delimiter separator!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if u want to do it in rdd:

```
rddd = df.rdd.map(
    lambda x: [re.sub(r"\\026", "", x[i].strip()) for i in range(len(x))]
).map(lambda x: [None if x[i] == "" else x[i].strip() for i in range(len(x))])

df2=rddd.toDF(["a","b","c","d"])

df2.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DV1W.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please brief me, the logic. I didn't understand